# how to create serializer for an enum field in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-serializer

i am writing an API in python django rest framework and i am stuck at creating a serializer field for an ENUM, how can i create a serializer field for an ENUM field.
my model code is:

```
class Queue(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'queues'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    type = EnumChoiceField(QueueTypes, default=QueueTypes.pending)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and i am writing a serializer for this model.

```
class QueueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Queue
        fields = ('__all__')

    id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=45, required=True)
    type=?????# what am i supposed to do here?
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

Comment: I can see that EnumChoiceField is a custom defined field. DRF supports defining custom field mapping also, have a look here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields maybe it helps.

Comment: yes its a custom defined field for the implementation of ENUM in the django model, thanks i'll check the link.

Comment: `EnumChoiceField` isn't part of Django. Where does it come from ?

Comment: i had this issue of creating an enum in the model.py i found a solution to this by searching on google that is django-enum choicefield, have a look [link](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-enumchoicefield/stable/django-enumchoicefield.pdf)

Comment: [EnumChoiceField](https://pypi.org/project/django-enumchoicefield/) doesn't support `filter_fields` in DRF's `ModelViewSet`.  Other than that, it seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`EnumChoiceField`](https://github.com/mx-moth/django-enumchoicefield) extension seems to work fine but does not correctly support the HTML support render of the *REST Framework*, fields serialized as `EnumChoiceField` are not rendered.

Answer (score 10):

After doing a lot of searches on google i finally found the answer to the serializing issue with the EnumchoiceField the following changes did the job.

my **Model.py**:

```
from enumchoicefield import ChoiceEnum, EnumChoiceField

class QueueTypes(ChoiceEnum):
    appointment = "appointment"
    wait = "wait"
    process = "process"
    pending = "pending"

class Queue(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       db_table = 'queues'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    type = EnumChoiceField(enum_class=QueueTypes , default=QueueTypes.process)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    fk_department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='department',null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my **Serialize.py**:

```
from enumchoicefield import ChoiceEnum, EnumChoiceField

class QueueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Queue
        fields = ('__all__')

    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=45, required=True)
    type = EnumChoiceField(enum_class=QueueTypes)
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

Comment: Since you are using `ModelSerializer`, why would you still declare `type=EnumChoiceField(...)`?  They are not necessary.  For read only field, you just need to declare them in `read_only_fields = ('id', 'date')` inside the Meta