# Accessing Django 3 TextChoices via an exposed API endpoint?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 3.0.4 with Django REST Framework 3.11.0 where I have a `models.py` like:

```py
from django.db import models

from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel


class SampleModel(TimeStampedModel):
    class Options(models.TextChoices):
        FOO = "A"
        BAR = "B"
        BAZ = "C"

    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=512)

    options = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Options.choices,
        default=Options.FOO
    )
```

I would like to be able to create an API endpoint to return a list of my `TextChoices` as a tuple.  I have a React frontend where I want to create a `<select>` dropdown with my list of choices.  If I can access the list of `TextChoices` via an API endpoint, I should be good to go.

```py
path("api/sample/choices/", views.SampleChoicesListView.as_view(), name="sample_choices")
```

I'm not sure what my `views.py` needs to look like to make this work...

```py
class SampleChoicesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
   pass
```

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this. I couldn't figure it out, but here's my research:

It does not appear that there is a TextChoicesField in DRF yet. 

Here's a question on how to create a serializer for an enum in DRF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088804/how-to-create-serializer-for-an-enum-field-in-django-rest-framework

The selected answer requires implementation of `django-enumchoicefield`. I think it should work since TextChoices is just an enum. I just couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Return the `SampleModel.Options.choices` as `Response` in an `APIView`

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

# other required imports

class SampleChoicesListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # SampleModel.Options.choices would return
        # [('A', 'Foo'), ('B', 'Bar'), ('C', 'Baz')]
        choices = SampleModel.Options.choices
        # format it into dictionary
        # choices = {choice[0]: choice[1] for choice in SampleModel.Options.choices}
        return Response(choices)
```

Add urlpattern to api urls

```py
path("options/", views.SampleChoicesListView.as_view(), name="options"),
```

List structure:

[image: list structure]

Dictionary structure:

[image: dictionay structure]

Answer (score 0):

It may be cleaner to instead make an OPTIONS request to the `SampleModel` endpoint which should enumerate the valid options for that field, and also saves you creating a separate endpoint just to list the options.  DRF should handle this all for you.