# Name returning a number after serializing data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a table service :

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

SERVICE_CHOICES = (
    ('Carpenter', 'Carpenter'),
    ('Driver', 'Driver'),
    ('Ambulanve', 'Ambulanve'),
    ('Spa', 'Spa'),
    ('Barber', 'Barber'),
    ('Cleaning', 'Cleaning'),
    ('Cook', 'Cook'),
)



class Service(models.Model):
    name  = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_worker': True},)

    service = models.CharField(choices=SERVICE_CHOICES,max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.service} - {self.name}'
```

and a table CustomUser :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_worker = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I am serializing the Service table below :

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'
```

But when I add a service from the admin panel, the name shows a number in the browser and not the string. How do I change it to show a the name and not a number?
[image]

Comment: It is `ForeignKey` relationship. So it returns the primary key of the related `CustomUser`. You need to create another serializer for `CustomUser` and use it in the `ServiceSerializer` or you can use `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` to get the name.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail or link docs/resource where I can understand more about this? Thanks

Comment: you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088804/how-to-create-serializer-for-an-enum-field-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `name` is a forignkey to `CustomUser`, and the default behavior is to return the PK related to the `CustomUser` instance.

Instead you could use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ServiceSerializer` you can try:

```py
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(ServiceSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['name'] = instance.name.name    # instance.name.what_you_use_in_Custom_User_model_to_represent_name
        return rep
```

However, consider whether this is what you want, because this change could lead to more problems than it solves.